# listview data not shows in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have a fragment **FragmentTab1** & I want to replace **AllContactsFragment** fragment  which consists a listview & two button. The replacement performs well, but data is not showing in **ListView**. Data shows in log cat as well.

The replacement code  Inside FragmentTab1 is:

```
AllContactsFragment allContactsFragment = new AllContactsFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.add(R.id.fragmentTabLayout1, allContactsFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

I fill up data in listview inside AllContactsFragment like:

```
    public class AllContactsFragment extends SherlockFragment implements
        OnClickListener {

    ListView listViewAllContact;
    Button btnAdd, btnCacel;
    List<BlockNumber> contactNumberlist;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_contacts, container,
                false);
        // data are comes well & checked in Log cat
        contactNumberlist = PhoneUtils.getAllContacts(getActivity());
        listViewAllContact = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.listViewAllContact);

        ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(),
                contactNumberlist, m_onSelectedEventCalender);

        listViewAllContact.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    } 
}
```

I also share my ContactListAdapter adapter

```
   public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<BlockNumber> allContactsNumbers = null;
    public Context context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder holder;

    private onSelectedEventCalender m_onSelectedEventCalender;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, List<BlockNumber> allNumberList,
            onSelectedEventCalender m_onSelectedEventCalender) {

        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.allContactsNumbers = allNumberList;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        this.m_onSelectedEventCalender = m_onSelectedEventCalender;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return allContactsNumbers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        try {

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                convertView.setMinimumHeight(50);

                holder.textViewContactName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textview_contact_name);

                holder.textView_Contact_Number = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textview_number);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                holder.textViewContactName.setText(allContactsNumbers.get(
                        position).getName());

                holder.textView_Contact_Number.setText(allContactsNumbers.get(
                        position).getNumber());

                holder.textViewContactName.setTag(allContactsNumbers
                        .get(position));

                return convertView;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("Exception", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewContactName;
        TextView textView_Contact_Number;
        // TextView textViewEventEndDate;
    }

    public interface onSelectedEventCalender {
        void onSelectedEventCalender(BlockNumber aBlockNumber, int type);

    }
}
```

Corresponding XML for AllContactsFragment is fragment_all_contacts.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_new" >

<!-- android:background="#80000000" -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutFragmentMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewAllContact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine1" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCanel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Home" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

May be I am missing something?

**Edited**: to make above code right.

remove  android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine1" from ListView definition XML , remove return null from getView() in adapter & check the data is available or not which is set to listview.

Comment: why try catch in `getView` remove that and this `return null`

Comment: also remove this  `if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }` and try

Comment: you have this  `android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine1"` where is view with id `imageViewLine1`

Comment: @Raghunandan: working with your advice

Comment: @Raghunandan stil not working..

Comment: you have this `android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine1"` where is view with id `imageViewLine1`. so where are you placing listview below which view?. i don't see any view with id `imageViewLine1` in your xml

Comment: @Raghunandan: i remove this android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine1"  & listview is in top of the layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39553/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-shihab-returns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woh! What a foolish I am? My **contactNumberlist** is empty because I don't add the object in the list. My Log cat misleading me.  Thanks for @Ragunandan & @tom nobleman for their great afford to find mistakes.

My ContactListAdapter getView() looks like :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        convertView.setMinimumHeight(50);

        holder.textViewContactName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textview_contact_name);
        holder.textView_Contact_Number = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textview_number);
        holder.imgViewContactImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgViewContactImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if (allContactsNumbers.size() <= 0) {
        holder.textViewContactName.setText("No Data");

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        String name = allContactsNumbers.get(position).getName();
        holder.textViewContactName.setText(name);

        String number = allContactsNumbers.get(position).getNumber();
        holder.textView_Contact_Number.setText(number);

        Uri Uri = allContactsNumbers.get(position).getImage_Uri();
        if (Uri != null) {
            holder.imgViewContactImage.setImageURI(Uri);
        } else {
            holder.imgViewContactImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_no_image);
        }

        Log.d("Contacts in Adapter", "" + name + "" + number);

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try

1) in xml set your listview "above" your linear-layout-button-bar

2) after creating ContactListAdapter adapter call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

3) in the adapter in the first if - after convertView.setTag(holder); set return convertView;

4) create and set the adapter in the onViewCreated() Method

or

replace your listview once with an imageview and look if you will see the image, than you know for sure that the listview is the one that fails (don't forget to set a background!)